# Improving the join of two wave file?

Tags: python, wav

I have written a code for joining two wave files.It works fine when i am joining larger segments but as i need to join very small segments the clarity is not good.

I have learned that the signal processing technique such a windowed join can be used to improve the joining of file.

y[n] = w[n]s[n]
Multiply value of signal at sample number n by the value of a windowing function
hamming window w[n]= .54 - .46*cos(2*Pi*n)/L   0

I am not understanding how to get the value to signal at sample n and how to implement this??

```
the code i am using for joining is

import wave
m=['C:/begpython/S0001_0002.wav', 'C:/begpython/S0001_0001.wav']
i=1
a=m[i]
infiles = [a, "C:/begpython/S0001_0002.wav", a]
outfile = "C:/begpython/S0001_00367.wav"

data= []
data1=[]
for infile in infiles:
    w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')
    data1=[w.getnframes]
    data.append( [w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())] )
    #data1 = [ord(character) for character in data1]

    #print data1
    #data1 = ''.join(chr(character) for character in data1)

    w.close()

output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
output.setparams(data[0][0])
output.writeframes(data[0][1])
output.writeframes(data[1][1])
output.writeframes(data[2][1])
output.close()
```

during joining i am manipulating using byte format for frames.now have to use integer or float format to perform operation on them i guess,if what i am thinking is true,how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the best solution, but I'm sure it will work. Maybe you find existing libs or so for some steps, I dont know for Python. The steps I suggest are:

1. Load the wave file.
2. Create the sample values (amplitude)
   for each frame (depending on frame
   size, litte/big endian,
   signed/unsigned).
3. Divide the resulting array of int
   values into windows, e.g. sample
   0-511, 512-1023, ...
4. Perform the window function, for the
   windows that you want to join.
5. Do your joining.
6. Store the windows back in a byte
   array, the inverse operation of the
   first step.

Old Post:
You have to calculate the sample value, in java a function for a 2 byte/frame soundfile would look like this:

```
public static int createIntFrom16( byte _8Bit1, byte _8Bit2 ) {
    return ( 8Bit1<<8 ) | ( 8Bit2 &0x00FF );
}
```

Normally you will have to care about whether or not the file uses little endian, I don't know if the Python lib will take this into account.

Once you have created all sample values, you have to divide your file into windows, e.g. of size 512 samples. Then you can window the values, and create back the byte values. For 16bit it would look like this:

```
public static byte[] createBytesFromInt(int i) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    bytes[0]=(byte)(i>>8);
    bytes[1]=(byte)i;
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: how to implement this is python
i am not used to java

Comment: Im not used to python sorry, but maybe someone elso who reads this can translate the functions.

Comment: if not translate can u just explain what are step and how is it done.i wil code it myself please

Answer (score 0):

To give you a high level understanding, WAV audio format consists of a 44 byte header where you define necessary meta data like sample rate, number of channels, etc. followed by the payload where the actual audio data lives.   Audio is simply a curve of amplitude change over time.  WAV format permits this amplitude to vary from a maximum value of +1.0 to minimum of -1.0 as expressed as a floating point.   As an audio recording is made this amplitude is measured typically 44100 times per second (sample rate).  So a WAV file just stores this series of sample values.  The WAV format does NOT store floating points, instead it stores the range of +1 to -1 as integers ranging from 0 to 2^16.  These 16 bit samples require two bytes of file storage per sample.  In example code like above the i>>8 is shifting the audio values by 8 bits.  If you think about these ideas, and write your own WAV format code to read or write from/to files you'll be well on your way to being able to answer your question.